# How many fixed points can a differentiable function have?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then could any one tell me which of the following statements are necessarily true?

1. If $f'(x)\le r<1$ for all $x$ then $f$ has at least one fixed point
2. If $f$ has a unique fixed point, then $f'(x)\le r<1$ for all $x$
3. If $f'(x)\le r<1$ for all $x$ then it has a unique fixed point.
4. If $f$ has a unique fixed point, then $f'(x)\ge r>-1$ for all $x$

We know that if $X$ is a complete metric space, $f:X\to X$ is a map such that $d(f(x),f(y)\le cd(x,y)$, where $0\le c<1$. Then $f$ has a unique fixed point, here by MVT we get $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert = \lvert f'(c)\rvert \cdot \lvert x-y \rvert$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is a contraction map and hence by above theorem $f$ has a unique fixed point so $1$ is true, what can be said more?

Comment: What if $f(x)<-1$ for some $x$? There is still a fixed point, but you can't use the contraction property, so you might need more work for (1) and (3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

For 2. consider $f(x)=2x$.

For 3. Let $a$ and $b$ be fixed points of $f$ and consider $\displaystyle\int_a^b f^\prime(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

For 4. consider $f(x) = -x$.

Comment: I dont understand your explanation and example on 3

Comment: @miosaki Let $b>a$ be fixed points of $f$. If $f^\prime \leq r$, then $\int_a^b f^\prime(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \leq r(b-a)$. On the other hand, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $\int_a^b f^\prime(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = f(b)-f(a) = b-a$. Thus we conclude that $r(b-a)\geq b-a$, for $r\leq 1$ and $b-a\geq 0$, which can only be true if $b-a=0$.

Comment: I think $b-a\le r(b-a)$?

Comment: @miosaki You are right. I corrected it now.

Comment: as $b\ne a$ so we are getting $r\ge 1$ a contradiction so $b-a=0$

Comment: @miosaki You don't need to derive a contradiction. The argument shows directly that any two fixed points are equal.